# JavaScript: Extract value from div element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a html page containing something like:

```
<div data-variableid2="1234"> </div>
```

How can I get the 1234 value of an element (without jQuery) and show it with `alert()` ?

Comment: is there a class or id or anything on the div? and are you using jQuery or straight javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should give your DIV an id.

```
<div id="myid" data-variableid2="1234"> </div>
```

Then you could display the attributes data using

```
var MyDiv1 = document.getElementById('myid');
alert(MyDiv1.getAttribute('data-variableid2'));
```

Just test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/5C4NA/

But if you are not allowed to change the HTML of your pages, you should stick to something like

```
document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0]
```

but the index (here `0`) does vary with the position of the div within the HTML page.

**Edit 1:**

With a loop you are able to scan through all DIVs and choose the one with an attribute `data-variableid2`: http://jsfiddle.net/5C4NA/1/ This looks like:

```
var elm = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for (i=0;i<elm.length;i++) {
    if (elm[i].getAttribute('data-variableid2')!=null) {
        alert(elm[i].getAttribute('data-variableid2'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Conent cannot be changed, the div doesn't have ID

Comment: But it's not first div, there are many nested divs and none of them have IDs, so maybe [0] attribute wouldn't help? It gives me null as value

Comment: As I said, the index may vary. See my edit for a loop example.

Answer (score 3):

```
var elm = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0]; //get element
alert(elm.getAttribute("data-variableid2")); //alert attribute
```

Note: you should add an id to the div and get the element by id (for performance).

This is done by plain Javascript, no jQuery required.

[getAttribute() Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute)

Comment: It is nested div, it's not the only one on the page

Comment: why can't you give IDs to the div?

Comment: because content of the html page cannot be changed

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you dont use jQuery, (because it wasn't tagged):

**HTML**: (I used id for div element to simplify things):

```
<div id="example" data-variableid2="1234"></div>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
// capture element
var example = document.getElementById('example');

// capture data variable value
var dataVar = example.getAttribute('data-variableid2');

// show it with alert
alert(dataVar);
```

Here is the example: **[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6zWUh/)**

**Edit:**

In case you cant use id or class for an element you can then capture it with this (0 is the number of the element):

```
var example = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
```

If (and most likely) its not the only div at the page, you can try **[querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)**

Like this:

```
// capture element - references to 0 which is the first matched element
// because this will select group of elements with data-variableid2
var example = document.querySelectorAll("[data-variableid2]")[0];
```

Here is the example with that: **[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6zWUh/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like that with jQuery

```
<div data-variableid2="1234"> </div>
<script>
     var data = $('div').attr('data-variableid2');
     alert(data);
</script>
```